# Pipelines in data factory are loading partial data

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, azure-data-factory

I have created some pipelines in data factory and the pipelines are reading files from the source, but they are writing partial data and not all data. I am not able to identify the root cause.

I am using ADF V2. I extracted all the .gz files and the total row count was 64448 and there are total 15 files. I have then checked the destination and the pipeline has written around half the records ie 31210.

I also tried loading just 1 file, of 4500 records and it wrote 2100 records.

Comment: No any error occurred in the pipelines?Have you checked whether the records was truncated in the fixed order?Or any timeout issue or fault tolerance?

Comment: @JayGong No errors. I truncated the destination table & then did the load. Data load is done successfully, with partial data.

Comment: Hi Dazesh, have you enabled skip incompatible rows? Could you share a pipeline run ID?

Answer (score 0):

You can use identity columns as the surrogate key to transfer data instead of timestamp column.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While helping individuals, we also try to produce a permanent source of future help for others - so answers that produce a tangible record are preferred. Before offering 1:1 help, read [this Meta post](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280603) and reconsider making the effort to document the answer.